# IPython FITS file plotting gives different results

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy

I am facing a problem while running a script ( please find the code below ).

I am trying to plot an array of values, write it into a FITS file format, read it back again and plot it ---> I don't get the same plots!

If you could please help me with this it would be great.

The following are the versions of my packages and compiler:

matplotlib : '2.0.0b1'

numpy : '1.11.0'

astropy : u'1.1.2'

python : 2.7

Sincerely,
Anik Halder

```
import numpy as np

from pylab import *

from astropy.io import fits

# Just making a 10x10 meshgrid
x = np.arange(10)
X , Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)

# finding the distance of different points on the meshgrid from a point suppose at (5,5)
Z = ((X-5)**2 + (Y-5)**2)**0.5 

# plotting Z (see image [link below] - left one)
imshow(Z, origin = "lower")
colorbar()
show()

# writing the Z data into a fits file
fits.writeto("my_file.fits", Z)

# reading the same fits file and storing the data
Z_read = fits.open("my_file.fits")[0].data

# plotting Z_read : we expect it to show the same plot as before
imshow(Z_read, origin = "lower")
colorbar()
show()

# Lo! That's not the case for me! It's not the same plot! (see image - right one)

# Hence, I try to check whether the values stored in Z and Z_read are different..

print Z - Z_read

# No! It returns an array full of zeros! This means Z and Z_read are the same! I don't get why the plots look different!
```

Please find the image in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6UQg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out to be that it's to do with the version of matplotlib.

Answered by a developer of matplotlib - Jens Nielsen

This doesn't occur on matplotlib version 1.51

In version 2 beta 1, it seems that the FITS data is converted from float32 to big endian float8. Please look at the following link:

https://gist.github.com/jenshnielsen/86d4a86d8f667fadddc09f88c5fb87e6

The issue has been posted and you can look it up over here:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6671

In the meantime for having the same plots (Z and Z _read) we should rather use the following code (for matplotlib 2 beta 1) :

```
imshow(Z_read.astype('float64'), origin = "lower")
```